# Коммерческий проект на основе открытых научных публикаций

Tags: алгоритм, авторские-права, статьи

Возможно ли использование метода (способа или алгоритма, модели и т. д.), описанного в открытой научной публикации (лицензия — произвольная), в коммерческом продукте с закрытым исходным кодом?

Вот есть публикация, у нее есть автор и владелец исключительных прав (как у любого произведения). Брать и копировать ТЕКСТ публикации без разрешения автора в соответствии с авторским правом запрещено (если автор не прикрепил соответствующей лицензии).

Если в ТЕКСТЕ публикации присутствует КОД, реализующий описанный в публикации метод, алгоритм и т. д., то тоже запрещено без разрешения его использовать.

Но вот можно ли, допустим, создать коммерческий продукт, основанный на описанном в статье методе, если всю реализацию метода в виде кода компания реализует самостоятельно? При этом никакие разрешения от автора не требуются.

Comment: Хоар написал статью про быструю сортировку в "Communications of the ACM" и в "The Computer Journal" и её многие используют в коммерческих продуктах.

Comment: Публиткация защищает авторские, но не имущественные права. Имущественные права защищает патент. Но, автор мог взять патент одновременно с написанием статьи, или может сделать это в будущем....

Comment: Вряд ли это о каких-то глобальных вещах, так что можно, используйте.

Comment: Увы дать точный ответ не получится, много мелких факторов которые нужно учесть, если ваш проект находится в другой от автора стране, либо полностью скрыт и невозможно узнать какие-то конкретные реализации, то шансов столкнуться с автором мало, но не равно 0, существуют целые компании, задача которых находить подобные вещи и подавать иски с компенсацией. Но это у нас не так распространено как в Китае или США. Если у проекта большое будущее то обратитесь в соответствующие инстанции для получения более компетентной информации и защиты своего продукта.

Comment: `всю реализацию метода в виде кода компания реализует самостоятельно` - да, так можно, это называется ["метод чистой комнаты"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) и широко используется.

Comment: @ESkri, т. е. судя по описанию если патента нет, то не важны какие-там авторские права у статьи, в которой описано и можно смело использовать?